# Access Denied when waiting for a Process started with Credentials

Tags: powershell, process

I have a script which runs in a user context of a user that does not have permission to Install Applications. I need to install an exe, so I need to do it  as a domain admin.

After the Installation I'd like to do other stuff in the script, but the Installation must be finished before continueing with the script.

When I `Wait-Process` for the installation to end, I get an access denied error.

Is there a way to wait for a Process to finish, which was started on another user context?

This is my code:

```
$P = Start-Process $Pfad\vcredist_x64.exe -Argumentlist "/install","/passive","/norestart" `
                         -WorkingDirectory $Pfad -Credential $cred -PassThru | Wait-Process
```

This are the error messages (translated from german):

Access denied

> Wait-Process : This command terminated the "vcredist_x64 (6284)" operation due to the following error: Access denied. In Zeile:6
>   Zeichen:84
>   + ...    -WorkingDirectory $Pfad -Credential $cred -PassThru | Wait-Process
>   +                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.Diagnost... (vcredist_x64):Process) [Wait-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessNotTerminated,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WaitProcessCommand

Timeout issue

> Wait-Process : This command terminated the process because the "vcredist_x64 (6284)" process was not completed within the specified timeout. In Zeile:6 Zeichen:84
>   + ...    -WorkingDirectory $Pfad -Credential $cred -PassThru | Wait-Process
>   +                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.Diagnost... (vcredist_x64):Process) [Wait-Process], TimeoutException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessNotTerminated,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WaitProcessCommand

Comment: Did you try Start-Process <exe path> -NoNewWindow -Wait 
or WaitForExit() Method

Comment: @Clint yes, with `-wait` I also get access denied, `WaitForExit()` does not work at all somehow

Comment: @Clint ok, somehow `WaitForExit` works now, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my earlier comment as an answer

```
$proc = Start-Process "Notepad.exe" -PassThru
$proc.WaitForExit()
$proc1 = Start-Process "Calc.exe" -PassThru
$proc1.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this the other day. My case was a little different. I was kicking something off, I wanted something to happen once that process ended, in the meantime I was doing another thing. For that, I used an event. Here is an example using Notepad:

```
$do_other_stuff = { 
    Write-Host 'Do Other Stuff'
    Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
}

$p = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
...do other stuff...

$job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $p `
    -EventName Exited `
    -SourceIdentifier notepad `
    -Action $do_other_stuff
```

If I wanted to wait for the even to trigger, I'd use `Wait-Event`. Stuff whatever you want done once the installer finishes running in the `$do_other_stuff` script block.

To your question, the following worked for me:

```
$p = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru -Wait
...do stuff...
```

As did...

```
$p = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
$p.WaitForExit()
...do stuff...
```

These cases worked when running the script in elevated and un-elevated context. It worked when passing credentials to `Start-Process` via the `-Credential` parameter. I wasn't able to try it where the account calling `Start-Process` is a low privileged account; I have a meeting in a few, sorry.